# MVC 3 - Entity Framework & POCO - Many to Many REMOVAL on ActionLink()

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, many-to-many, html.actionlink

**I have Many to Many Relationships for:**

> Company -----> CompanyVenue <------
>   Venue

I can currently add a Venues to a Companies and Companies to Venues.

[image]
The Add Venue link takes the user to this view: (using this controller logic):

```
var venue = context.Companies.Select(x => x.Venues.Where(xy => xy.VenueId == id));
var company = venue.Select(x => x.);
ViewData["CompanyFor"] = company;
ViewData["VenueFor"] = venue;
```

[image]
Once the User Selects the Venue and Clicks the **ADD VENUE** Button, it passes the ViewModel back to Controller:

```
Company c = context.Companies.Single(x => x.CompanyId == model.CompanyId);
Venue v = context.Venues.Single(x => x.VenueId == model.VenueId);
c.Venues.Add(v);
context.SaveChanges();
```

---

So That is how I implimented the Many-Many Add. But, I Am looking for some help with **Removal** Controller Code / View (If Needed) / Possibly A View Model (but don't really see the need for what is essential a simple action)

In the Company Details View I am trying to get **REMOVE Link** underneath each Venue Item to Remove the [CompanyVenue] (many2many) Relationship.

If it is possible to pass 2 Values instead of one using this type of ActionLink():

```
@Html.ActionLink("Remove", "VenueRemove", new { Id = venue.VenueId }, new { Cid = model.CompanyId } )
```

it would be easy, but I have not figured out a way (load method) to pass both Values ( Id & Cid ) back to a VenueRemove() Controller Action, that would then return a RedirectToAction() back to the Company Details view.

**If someone knows how to do that Please let me know.** (Thank You Darin for the awnser to that)

I went ahead and got the Remove Working Using a View.

But is there anyway to get the Remove to work by just clicking the REMOVE Link/button and have it remove the venue with out going to the view?

Maybe an AJAX request or something.... ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass two parameters to the `VenueRemove` action like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Remove", 
    "VenueRemove", 
    new { 
        Id = venue.VenueId, 
        Cid = model.CompanyId 
    }
)
```

Comment: You know I just figured that out about 5 minutes before I checked back here to see if anyone responded. After Figuring that out, I added some controller code to use the 2 IDs: ||| Company c = context.Companies.Single(x => x.CompanyId == Cid);
            Venue v = context.Venues.Single(x => x.VenueId == Id);
            c.Venues.Remove(v);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = Cid }); ||| But I am getting an Error (Requested URL: /Company/VenueRemove/2) ||| is there a way to get the Action() to work with out linking to that?

Comment: I guess I can create a View now to handle that, but I was sorta hoping that it is possible with out having to send the User to another view to APPROVE the removal, since when I get further along in this app, there will be several 1000 Employee ---> EmployeeCustomer <--- Customer Relationships, and I can see getting some complaints down the line of the removal process takes to long.